# Magento 2.3.1 - Luma Theme - Feature Product Noob Way

Tags: magento2.3.1, featured-product

So Magento luma theme has a build-in featured product shown at the home page

How do I put the new product as featured?

In Magento 1 / Wordpress it's as simple as click STAR button at product catalog backend

Is there such a simple method for Magento 2.3.1?